# Calculus for functions $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb C$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, functions, derivatives

I'll start with the example that has sparked this doubt. Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued function of a real variable $x$, and define $g(x)=|f(x)|^2$. Then the derivative of this function is $$g'(x)=2f(x)f'(x).$$

Now suppose that $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb C$. Does anything change in the derivative of $g$ in the case of $f$ being a complex-valued function of a real variable? In general, is there any difference between calculus done in $\mathbb R$ and calculus for functions that can map real numbers into the complex plane?

Comment: $f(x)=f_1(x)+if_2(x)$ so $|f(x)|^2=f_1(x)^2+f_2(x)^2$ and $g'(x)=2f_1(x)f_1'(x)+2f_2(x)f_2'(x).$ Your formula for $g'$ would be accurate for $g(x)=f(x)^2.$ For real values functions, $|f(x)|^2=f(x)^2,$ so the two answers coincide.

Comment: Also, for complex-valued $f$, we have $g'(x)= 2 \operatorname{Re} f(x)f'(x)$ (from the above calculation).

Comment: @Pedro Wait: $ff'=f_1f_1'-f_2f_2'+i(f_1f_2'+f_2f_1')$, so $2\text{ Re}(ff')=2f_1f_1'-2f_2f_2'$. Isn't this off by a sign?

Comment: Oh, sorry. The correct (widely used) formula is $g'(x)= 2 \operatorname{Re} f(x)\overline{f'(x)}$ (where the bar is the complex conjugate).